# What is the scope and persistence of add_filter() and remove_filter()?

Tags: filters

I understand that using add_filter() or remove_filter() directly within a themes' functions.php would make the changes global across the theme unless you override them elsewhere. But believe this is a result of WordPress initialization.

```
add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

However if a call to add_filter() or remove_filter() is made within a function or class:

```
function example(){
    ...
    add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
    ...
}
```

What is the scope and persistence of the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always global. `add_filter()` and `add_action()` are just wrapper for the global variable `$wp_filter`. So it doesn’t matter where the function is called.

The same is true for `apply_filters()`, `apply_filters_ref_array()`, `do_action_ref_array()` and `do_action()`: they work in the global namespace, that’s the reason why the callback handlers (functions or methods) have to be public. A protected class method cannot be called from the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the much needed Homer Simpson moment.